# How can I retrieve datacolumns in different order to that defined by the datatable?

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with 5 rows and want to read data into a grid view. At the moment in reads the information one column at a time.

But I want to read the information in this order

```
col1 | col2 | col4 | col5 | col3 | col6 |
     |      |      |      |      |      |
```

The data is on a datatable not sql table

and its in c# code

Comment: Define another hidden column called "Order" which is an integer type and use it to order by your collection.

Comment: Where from you are reading the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `*` when you're selecting from the database. Instead list all column names in the desired order explicitly:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col4,col5,ol3,col6
FROM dbo.TableName
ORDER BY desired_column
```

You can also modify the order easily in the `GridView` itself. Just change the order of it's [`GridViewColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx).

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server">

    <columns>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="col1" headertext="col1"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="col2" headertext="col2"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="col3" headertext="col3"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="col4" headertext="col4"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="col5" headertext="col5"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="col6" headertext="col6"/>
    </columns>

</asp:gridview>
```

Comment: @TarangPatel: A `DataTable` is usually filled from database with a `DataAdapter`. You havent mentioned how it is filled. However, i've also showed how to show the desired order in your `GridView`.

Comment: yeah but the data is excel not sql

Comment: @TarangPatel: If that is related to your question, edit it and add this information to it. But how is it related? I thought that you just want to know how to control the order of the columns in your `GridView`. Do you want to order the columns (as stated in the question) or do you want to order the rows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can set the ordinal of the columns

```
dataTable.Columns[1].SetOrdinal(0);
```